# TestNG only running the first test in a suite

Tags: java, testng

I have a testng.xml file with two tests:

```
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" >
<suite name="XEP-0100" verbose="1">
    <test name="Registration">
        <classes>
            <class name="com.obscured.xmpp.TestRegister" />
        </classes>
    </test>
    <test name="Login">
        <classes>
            <class name="com.obscured.xmpp.TestLogin" />
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```

Unfortunately, the Eclipse TestNG plugin is only running a single test when running against the testng.xml:

[image]

If I put the TestLogin class underneath the Registration test, it runs.  Even more strange: the progress bar says "Tests 2/2"!  What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the plug-in actually ran both tests but is only reporting one and I see nothing wrong with what you posted. Can you create a small self-contained Eclipse project and email it to me? If I can reproduce this, I should be able to fix it quickly.

Comment: I am embarassed to say that both tests failed due to a bad group dependency and I should have noticed this in the console... It would probably be best if the plugin view reported these as test failures.  You have developed a great product, thanks.

Comment: Actually, it seems like any unchecked exception causes the plugin to not display a test as a failure.  This is a departure from the behavior of the JUnit plugin and will probably be a surprise to many making the crossover.

Comment: Yes, the plug-in could definitely do a better job here, you shouldn't have to monitor the console to find errors, that's what the view is for. Still, it would help if you could email me a small Eclipse project that I can use to reproduce the problem. Thanks!

Comment: Please, send him a project that causes the problem. It's not often you have the developer of the project reaching out like this!

Answer (score 0):

It might have something to do with the Eclipse plugin setup. Do you have it configured to run your specific test.xml file? Or are you just running the test named Registration?

[TestNG Eclipse documentation](http://testng.org/doc/eclipse.html)

Section 3.3 talks about running testng.xml files.

Comment: Good question.  I am running on the testng.xml file.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are only running your two test classes, what happens if you set up the group on the tests you would like to run, or run the whole package?

From TestNG doc:

```
<test name="Regression1">
  <groups>
    <run>
      <exclude name="brokenTests"  />
      <include name="checkinTests"  />
    </run>
  </groups>

  <classes>
    <class name="test.IndividualMethodsTest">
      <methods>
        <include name="testMethod" />
      </methods>
    </class>
  </classes>
</test>
```

Comment: I can see how one would want to use groups in certain situations, but just two examples up from the one you site in Chapter 3 of the TestNG documentation is an example that looks very similar to mine.

Answer (score 0):

I saw the same issue in version 6.13.1, 6.14.2 and 6.14.3, but since 7.0.0-beta1 everything works fine.

More on: https://github.com/cbeust/testng/issues/1639